# passing an argument to spiders __init__

Tags: python, scrapy

```
cities = ['LED', 'KUL', 'MOW']
sp = AirwaySpider(cities)
```

gives the error

```
sp = AirwaySpider(cities)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

From the AirwaySpider code:

```
class AirwaySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(AirwaySpider, self).__init__(**kw)
        cities = kw
```

while this would work

```
sp = AirwaySpider(domain="sdf")
```

I understand what the "self" is for, and what is ** in C++, but don't know what this notation means in python and why I can't pass the list where dict (the dict is passed in the example from which I've taken the code)  is OK.

UPDATE:

if I change the code to pass raw single argument it works first, but then fails later in the framework:

```
class AirwaySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    def __init__(self, kw):
        super(AirwaySpider, self).__init__(kw)
```

error

```
File "airway.py", line 13, in <module>
process.crawl(sp)
...
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 80, in   _create_spider
return self.spidercls.from_crawler(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders\__init__.py", line 50, in        from_crawler
spider = cls(*args, **kwargs)
exceptions.TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
2015-12-16 15:57:29 [twisted] CRITICAL:
```

Answer (score 1):

> **kwargs allows you to pass keyworded variable length of arguments to a function. You should use **kwargs if you want to handle named arguments in a function.

Read this link for details: [args and kwargs in python explained](http://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/)

So for your function to work need to specify the name of the argument:

`sp = AirwaySpider(cities=cities)`

Answer (score 1):

```
def test(a, **args):
    print args  # args is a dict

test(1, prame1=1, parame2=2)
```

output:

```
{'parame2': 2, 'parame1': 1}
```

** can receive all extra parames in the form of 'parame=value' and convert them to dict.

```
def test(param1, param2):
    print param1
    print param2
param = {'parame1': 1, 'parame2': 2}
test(**param)  
test(prame1=1, parame2=2)  # These two lines are equivalent.
```

output:

```
1
2
1
2
```

When **dict is used as param, it will be converted to 'key=value'